# Rails 4, SQ Lite 3: NoMethodError - undefined method: nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I've created a Notification Model which `belongs_to` a User (Devise) and each User `has_many` Notifications.
However I somehow can't get the Notifications in my Applications Controller or any other Controller:

```
def notifications
    @notifications = Notification.where(user_id: current_user.id).order('created_at desc')
end
```

I always seem to get `nil` as Object.

**For example:**
Recipes / Search View (views/items/search.html.haml):

```
- if @notifications.exists?
```

gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass
```

In my console I can get the Notifications with the following:

```
Notification.where(user_id: 3)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `- if @notifcations.exists?` is this code present in notifications.html.erb/haml?

Comment: in your notifications method, current_user.notifications is nil, nothing get assign to @notifications, that's why you got nil:NilClass error.

Comment: There is spelling mistake in `- if @notifcations.exists?` try  `- if @notifications.exists?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is spelling mistake in `- if @notifcations.exists?` try  `- if @notifications.exists?`

I suggest you change your code to

In user.rb

```
def ordered_notifications
   notifications.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

In your view

```
- if @current_user.ordered_notifications.exists?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sadly that doesn't fix the problem I still get that error...

Comment: @Gugubaight what is the file name of view file ?

Comment: @Gugubaight Are you rendering `search` in `notifications method` ? like `render :search`

Comment: @Gugubaight What is the name of controller in which you have defined `notifications` method?

Comment: No, how exactly am I supposed to do this (:o) :) (I updated the question and added a little bit more information)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125900/discussion-between-dinesh-and-gugubaight).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
- if @notifications.any?
```

Then you won't get *NoMethodError* and if it's empty it'll be treated as false